# question related to perfect maps preserving compactness

Tags: general-topology

A *perfect map* $f$ is a closed continuous surjective function such that the preimage of every point is compact. One property of perfect maps is that if 
$f \, \colon \, X \to Y$ is perfect, and $Y$ is compact, then $X$ is compact too.

My question (rephrased): if $f$ is a continuous surjective function such that the preimage of every point is compact, and $Y$ is compact, does it follow that $X$ is compact?

Comment: I think that such a map is automatically closed if $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: i think it's closed if Y is Hausdorff.

Comment: yes, i rephrased my question, hopefully it's clear now.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Let $Y$ be the closed unit interval with the usual Euclidean topology, and let $X$ be the closed unit interval with the discrete topology. Let $f:X\to Y$ be the identity map. Clearly $f$ is continuous and surjective and has compact fibres, and $Y$ is compact, but $X$ is not. Note that $X$ and $Y$ are even metrizable, so they’re about as nice as one could hope for.

Comment: what is a compact fiber/fibre?

Comment: @Alex: The fibres of a map are the preimages of points under that map.