# Compact Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [question related to perfect maps preserving compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90937/question-related-to-perfect-maps-preserving-compactness)

Let $Z$ be a compact topological space and let $Y$ be a topological space. Let $f:Y \rightarrow Z$ be a surjective continuous map so that the preimages of points are always compact. Does $Y$ have to be compact?

Comment: This was [asked and answered recently](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90937/question-related-to-perfect-maps-preserving-compactness).

Answer (score 0):

let $Y=\Big(\coprod_n (0,1/n]\Big)\coprod\{0\}$ and $Z=[0,1]$ with $f$ just the inclusion on the various pieces of $Y$.

Comment: what do you mean by an "inclusion on the various pieces of Y"

Comment: @james $Y$ is a disjoint union of subspaces of $Z$ and $f$ is just the identity on these pieces.  the point of the construction is that each $z\in Z$ has only finitely many preimages.